# Golang BigQuery: Insert array into table

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I'm trying to insert an array into a table using the bigquery golang library.

I have a table schema that looks like this. The array is the `quality` column, has the `Repeated`.

```
    tableSchema := bigquery.Schema{
        {Name: "issue_id", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType},
        {Name: "quality", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType, Repeated: true},
        {Name: "creation_date_ts", Type: bigquery.TimestampFieldType},
    }
```

This is how I defined the record:

```
type escalationsRecord struct {
    IssueID      bigquery.NullString    `bigquery:"issue_id"`
    Quality      []string               `bigquery:"quality"`
    CreationTime bigquery.NullTimestamp `bigquery:"creation_date_ts"`
}
```

This is how I create a record:

```
    record := escalationsRecord{
            IssueID:      bigquery.NullString{StringVal: fmt.Sprint(int(issue.Number)), Valid: true},
            Quality:      qualityArray,
            CreationTime: bigquery.NullTimestamp{Timestamp: issue.CreatedAt.Time, Valid: true},
        }
records = append(records, &record)
```

This is how I put the records to BigQuery

```
inserter := table.Inserter()
err2 := inserter.Put(b.ctx, records)
```

The `quality` column is NULL when I look at it in bigqyery. There are no errors. The array contains elements.
Any idea how to properly insert arrays? I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Can you show how the qualityArray is built? I'm testing with something similar to what you have and don't have any issues storing multiple values. I wonder if the issue is defining the schema value as `bigquery.StringFieldType` and that doesn't match what the struct has (assuming it's []string). You may try using the bigquery.InferSchema() method of defining the schema from a struct to ensure it matches.

Comment: @BrianWagner using InferSchema did the trick! Mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @BrianWagner suggested in his comment works. The only change I did was to use the `InferSchema()` instead of defining it myself.

So instead of

```
  tableSchema := bigquery.Schema{
        {Name: "issue_id", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType},
        {Name: "quality", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType, Repeated: true},
        {Name: "creation_date_ts", Type: bigquery.TimestampFieldType},
    }
```

I now have

```
    tableSchema, err := bigquery.InferSchema(escalationsRecord{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```